# A function that uses requests in order get JSON content

Tags: python, python-3.x

Any typing, or other improvements that you could make for this simple function?

```py
def get_json_parsed_from(url: Union[str, bytes]) -> Dict[Any, Any]:
    """Gets a JSON file and returns it parsed, or returns an empty dict if any error occurred."""
    try:
        headers = random_headers()
        headers['Accept'] = 'application/json,text/*;q=0.99'
        return dict(requests.get(url, headers=random_headers()).json())
    except BaseException:
        _LOGGER.exception('Failed getting JSON from %s', repr(url), exc_info=False)
        return {}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

```
headers = random_headers()
headers['Accept'] = 'application/json,text/*;q=0.99'   
return dict(requests.get(url, headers=random_headers()).json())
```

- You are not using `headers`. You create it and adding the `Accept` key to it, but then passing a new call to `random_headers()` to `.get` instead of using `headers`.
- `requests.get(...).json()` already returns a `dict`. Passing it to `dict(...)` is superfluous.

This should be your code:

```
headers = random_headers()
headers['Accept'] = 'application/json,text/*;q=0.99'   
return requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

Comment: You know what's strange? When I don't surround it with dict(), mypy complains that `warning: Returning Any from function declared to return "Dict[Any, Any]"`. Is this mypy being wrong? Also, if I look up the method definition of .json() in PyCharm, I see `def json(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Any`. It says it returns `Any`.

Comment: Wow, good spotting on the `headers` issue! You're a freaking genius! Thank you!

Comment: It tells you that because JSON could be an object (dict), array (list) or a primitive (str, float, int, ...).

Comment: I updated the function from the code review question, still taking into consideration that json() can return other stuff than dict. Is that good now?

Comment: @jonrsharpe so then, in the function signature I should have `-> Any:`, right?